# pyspark: DataFrame.withColumn() sometimes requires assignment to a new DataFrame with a different name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This seems to specifically happen when I'm multiplying a numeric column by a scalar, write the DataFrame back to HDFS, then try to look at the value when I load it into a DataFrame again. Doesn't happen in the pyspark shell, for example.

`df = df.withColumn('AMOUNT', df.AMOUNT*lit(-1))` => doesn't flip the column

`df_new = df.withColumn('AMOUNT', df.AMOUNT*lit(-1))` => works!

When I use other methods or UDFs, it doesn't seem to exhibit the same weirdness. I can just assign the DataFrame back to itself. Even if I created a brand new column with a different name, it doesn't show up in the output when I try to read it back in from HDFS.

This is part of a spark-submit'ed a job in yarn-cluster mode. PySpark 2.2.0.

Is there something buried in the documentation that I wasn't able to dig up or maybe something specific with my instance?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your issue (Spark 2.2.0):

```python
spark.version
# u'2.2.0'

import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# some data
dd = sc.parallelize([(2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (2.0, np.array([ 2.09078012])), (1.0, np.array([ 2.09078012]))])
dd.take(1)
# [(2.0, array([ 2.09078012]))]

df = dd.map(lambda x: (x[0], Vectors.dense(x[1]))).toDF()
df.show()    
# +---+------------+ 
# | _1|          _2|
# +---+------------+
# |2.0|[2.09078012]| 
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |1.0|[2.09078012]|
# |2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |1.0|[2.09078012]|
# +---+------------+

df = df.withColumn('_1', df._1*lit(-1))
df.show()
# +----+------------+ 
# |  _1|          _2|
# +----+------------+
# |-2.0|[2.09078012]| 
# |-2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |-2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |-1.0|[2.09078012]|
# |-2.0|[2.09078012]|
# |-1.0|[2.09078012]|
# +---+-------------+
```

Adding explicit column names and testing it with different underlying versions of Scala (2.11 & 2.10) does not change the behavior.

Comment: was that within the shell? it's fine there. i see it when it's through spark-submit in yarn-cluster mode, writing the df to HDFS (parquet), then loading it back from HDFS separately afterward.

Comment: @jastang It is in a Databricks notebook; if so, you should stress it accordingly in the post, plus provide a minimal *reproducible* example - otherwise cannot see how anyone could be of help